# Why log4net log message have some unknown character?

Tags: log4net

I use log4net for logging my logs.
and use configuration here (only log the message):

```
    <logger name="LogTracking">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogTrackingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="LogTrackingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logging\urltracking\" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <datePattern value="yyyy'\\'MM'\\'dd'\\'yyyyMMddHH'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    </appender>
```

But when i open my logs file, if in UTF-8 encoding the lines message seems normal. And if in ANSI encoding, these lines message have a unknown character at the beginning of the lines.
See here:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><UrlTrackingObj><Url>mysite</Url><Action>view</Action><Ip>::1</Ip><Os>Windows 8.1</Os><Browser>Chrome 59.0</Browser></UrlTrackingObj>
```

Then when my app reads log lines, it can read and process this character.
What is my configuration wrong? or any solution this solve this problem?
I want my log line only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><UrlTrackingObj><Url>mysite</Url><Action>view</Action><Ip>::1</Ip><Os>Windows 8.1</Os><Browser>Chrome 59.0</Browser></UrlTrackingObj>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those characters `ï»¿` are the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence
>   0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text
>   as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

You can use the other encoding class rather than the default one to suppress the `BOM` such as:

```
<encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding"/>
```

[System.Text.UTF8Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It means that i must replace `<encoding value="utf-8" />` by `<encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding"/>`?

Comment: @SonNguyen ukm just add `type` attribute to  `encoding` tag.

Comment: @SonNguyen you should accept the answer if it helps to solve your problem, which is very useful for later-coming users. :) Please refer this: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: This helped me to get rid of logging Chinese(?) characters and the NULL characters when using `<encoding value="UTF-8">`