# Log4NET Error: Failed to Find Type System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, log4net

I'm trying to use Log4Net's Rolling File Appender to create a log file whenever there is an issue with my data. Because I work with diacritics and non-Latin characters, I want the file encoding to be in UTF-8.

Normally, if the file doesn't have any diacritics/non-Latin characters, it's encoded as ASCII. If it does log diacritics/non-Latin characters, it'll automatically encode it to UTF-8. I want it to always be in UTF-8.

My first solution was to use `<encoding value="utf-8"/>`. This gives me UTF-8 with BOM, which is something I don't want. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838062/why-log4net-log-message-have-some-unknown-character) Stackoverflow solution told me to use `<encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding"/>`. I tried it and I would get this error:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding' from assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
log4net:ERROR Failed to create object to set param: encoding
```

I tried digging around on Apache's Jira and found this [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-329) which also told me to use `<encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding"/>`, which was the same as the Stackoverflow solution.

I then assumed maybe it's because I'm using .NET Core 2.2 and I had to try a different type. I also tried `<encoding type="System.Text.Encoding.UTF8"/>`, `<encoding type="UTF8Encoding"/>`, `<encoding type="Encoding.UTF8"/>` but none of these worked as well.

Here is the appender part of my XML:

```
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="WARN" />
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <!--<encoding value="utf-8"/>-->
      <encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1GB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    </appender>
```

Is there a different setting I need to do?

Comment: What's the difference between "in ascii until there's a non-ascii character, then converts to utf-8" and "always in utf-8", given that characters which are part of ascii have identical encodings in ascii and utf-8?

Comment: So far from what I've noticed, the file is encoded to UTF-8 once it has a non-Latin character such as having diacritics or a foreign language (Korean, Japanese, etc). I'm trying to make another script that has to detect the file encoding before doing something, but at this point I might just have a script that will detect both

Comment: My point is, ASCII is perfectly valid UTF-8. If you have a file encoded in ASCII, you can decode it using UTF-8, because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Any script that detects whether a file is UTF-8 will also detect ASCII as being valid UTF-8.